# jquery easy image slider

Tags: jquery

Using easy slider to scroll through Images .

It's working occasionally (on a refresh), but more often not.
The height of the slide and also the position get screwed up on load for seconds.

This style was applied to the 
 
style="width: 1308px; height: 70px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden;"

I'm not sure where it's pulling those values from (height and width) the slide not expanding vertically to reveal the content and the slide being out of position horizontally. I have this style applied to #slider
width:538px;
height:auto;
overflow:hidden;

but they're not being passed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your initializing the javascript AFTER the location of the div elements in your HTML.  At the very end before the ending body tag is safest bet.

Comment: i am sure...still no solution :(

Comment: you need to post your snippets of code in order for anyone to help. JS HTML and CSS